# Merging between forks in git repository

Tags: git, merge

I have forked a repository 'B' from main repository 'A'. Now there are some changes done to A and also B now. Now I am going to push the local changes of B into B repository. But before pushing to B, I want to pull the changes done to repo A into my local. Merge it and then push the net changes to my B repo. Later I have to raise a pull request to my A repo so that my approver can approve the code.

Currently, when I try to pull the changes done to A, I get the below error.

On branch development
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/development' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error but rather a point of information. It's telling you that your local tracking branch of the `origin/development` branch (likely called `development`, but technically it can have any name), has commits that aren't present in the `origin` repository's `development` branch.

Given that you just issued `git pull`, you most likely had a commit locally you hadn't yet pushed, and the second commit is a merge commit conducted by the `git pull` operation.

You can tell which commits you have that origin doesn't with

```
git log origin/development..<branch>`
```

where `<branch>` is whatever your local tracking branch is called. Technically, there's no reason you can't execute the rest of your plan. Just make sure you know what you're pushing, first.